# Bash, how to get the average execution time of multiple average execution times?

Tags: bash, time, execution

For a project, I need to determine which programming language executes the fastest, so I've got a whole bunch of hello worlds. I need to get the average of 1000 iterations, then I need the average of 100 of those 1000s. My knowledge of bash is rather limited. I've read up on the time command, and for loops, but I can't figure out how to grab the result of the command, and add it up.

Any help here would be very appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`time for i in {1..1000}; do something; done`

or

`{ time for i in {1..1000}; do perl -e 'print "foo";' >/dev/null 2>&1; done ; } 2>perl`

`{ time for i in {1..1000}; do  ruby -e 'print "foo"' >/dev/null 2>&1; done ; } 2>ruby`

do that for your languages then just do the math

`cat perl | grep real | awk '{print $2}'` will get you the times.

then calculate the averages based on those.

I can't go too much further without doing your work for you